# Rancidité, rancœur, et rancune : quelles différences ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, étymologie

J'ai ajouté *rancidité* dans la liste car la racine semble commune avec les autres (du latin *rancor*) et pour les éventuels rapports étymologiques, mais c'est notamment la paire *rancœur* / *rancune* qui m'intéresse.

En effet, malgré plusieurs lectures des définitions *(voir ici par exemple : [rancidité](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/rancidit%C3%A9), [rancœur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rancoeur), [rancune](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rancune)*), j'avoue avoir du mal à saisir correctement les différences qui peuvent les opposer. Différence de sens propre / sens figuré ? Différence de registre ? L'un remplaçant [progressivement](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rancune%2C%20rancoeur%2C%20ranc%C5%93ur&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crancune%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancoeur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cranc%C5%93ur%3B%2Cc0) l'autre dans l'emploi ? Lequel est le plus "littéraire" ? *Rancune* est-il plus spécifiquement employé pour un sentiment à l'égard d'une personne, et *rancœur* à l'égard une situation ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il s'agit au départ littéralement de la pourriture et de l'odeur; de [*rance*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/rance?idf=complXrmYXcbcghi;str=0) ([*rancidus*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/rance)) - [*rancir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rancir) (devenir rance; souvent pron. avec se) - [ranci](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ranci) (mais *Baudel.* pour le substantif d'ambiance en 1867). *Rancune* est une transformation de [*rancure*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/rancure?idf=dmfXgXrmXrbaa;str=0) sous l'influence d'*amertume*, et c'est à l'origine la colère puis, avec atténuation, le sens de souvenir précis avec idée de se venger finit par s'imposer; on a déjà eu [*rancurer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/rancurer?idf=complXrmYXcbcgja;str=0) (d'un latin [*rancura*](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/RANCURA), lui-même de [*rancor*](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=rancor)). Et on a [rancoeur](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/rancoeur), une réfection du 15e avec coeur de mots plus anciens basés sur *rancor*. En résumé rancune provient de rancoeur qui lui veut essentiellement dire rancune!! Puis [Charles Baudelaire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Baudelaire) vient fermer le bal dans [*Les Fleurs du mal*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Fleurs_du_mal) (1857/1868) puisqu'on lui doit en 1856 le sens d' « *amertume que laisse une déception, une injustice*. » pour rancoeur (selon le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sous dir. A. Rey, ed. Le Robert - « rancoeur ») et c'est surtout en ce sens-là que la différence existe. Voici entre autres les passages auxquels on fait forcément référence<sup>1</sup> :

> Pour noyer la **rancoeur** [1856] et bercer l'indolence
>  De tous ces vieux maudits qui meurent en silence,
>  Dieu, touché de remords, avait
>   fait le sommeil;
>  L'Homme ajouta le Vin, fils sacré du
>   Soleil!
>
> [**Le Vin de chiffonniers**](http://fleursdumal.org/poem/193), extrait, *Les Fleurs du mal*
>
> Je sucerai, pour noyer ma *rancoeur*,
>  Le népenthès et la bonne ciguë
>  Aux bouts charmants de cette gorge aiguë
>  Qui n'a
>   jamais emprisonné de coeur.
>
> [*Le Léthé*](http://baudelaire.litteratura.com/?rub=oeuvre&srub=pov&id=355), extrait, *Les Fleurs du mal*
>
> Il [le Vertige] la [l'âme] terrasse au bord d'un gouffre séculaire,
>  Où, Lazare odorant
>   déchirant son suaire,
>  Se meut dans son réveil le cadavre
>   spectral
>  D'un vieil amour *ranci*, charmant et sépulcral.
>
> [*Le Flacon*](http://fleursdumal.org/poem/143), extrait, *Les Fleurs du mal*
>
> Et ce parfum d'un autre monde, dont je m'enivrais avec une sensibilité perfectionnée, hélas! il est remplacé par une fétide odeur
>   de tabac mêlée à je ne sais quelle nauséabonde moisissure. On respire
>   ici maintenant le **ranci** [1867] de la désolation.
>
> [**La chambre double**](http://baudelaire.litteratura.com/?rub=oeuvre&srub=pop&id=143), extrait, *Le Spleen de Paris*, aussi 1864 dans
>   *Petits poèmes en prose*
>
> Un matin nous partons, le cerveau plein de flamme,
>  Le cœur gros
>   de *rancune* et de désirs amers,
>  Et nous allons, suivant le
>   rythme de la lame,
>  Berçant notre infini sur le fini des mers :
>
> [*Le Voyage*](http://baudelaire.litteratura.com/?rub=oeuvre&srub=pov&id=137), extrait, *Les Fleurs du mal*

Tous assurément littéraires. La rancune anime, la rancoeur, déprime ? On peut ouvrir au maximum la recherche ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rancune%2Crancoeur%2Cranc%C5%93ur%2Crancueur%2Crancuneux%2Crancuneuse%2Crancunier%2Crancuni%C3%A8re%2Crancour%2Crancor%2Crancir%2Crance&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crancune%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancoeur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cranc%C5%93ur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancueur%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancuneux%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancuneuse%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancunier%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancuni%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crancir%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crance%3B%2Cc0); on peut se questionner par exemple sur le rôle de l'adjectif *rancunier*), ou préférablement jeter un coup d'oeil sur *Gallica* vu la nature du corpus et les fonctions de l'outil (découpage par auteur/siècle etc.). <sup>2</sup> Les données semblent aller dans le même sens que la tendance présentée en question, quoique les résultats bruts constituent un portrait incomplet vu les sens différents selon les époques pour *rancoeur* par exemple. Un exemple particulier :

> "Rancune est populaire, mais rancœur serait noble et plus fort que
>   ressentiment",

De Marmontel (1723-1799), *Œuv.* t. X, p. 430, au *Littré*, où on voyait [rancoeur](http://www.littre.org/definition/rancoeur) comme vieilli (« *Haine cachée et invétérée qu'on garde dans le cœur ; même sens que rancune, mais d'un style plus élevé*. »). La rancoeur est possiblement rattachée à un objet plus abstrait que celui de la rancune.

---

<sub>1. [*Recherche*](http://baudelaire.litteratura.com/?rub=recherche&srub=roe) dans l’œuvre. Consultation facile de [Les Fleurs du mal](http://fleursdumal.org/) ([aussi](http://baudelaire.litteratura.com/?rub=oeuvre&srub=pov)). *Rancoeur+Baudelaire* sur [*Gallica*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?ArianeWireIndex=index&lang=EN&f_typedoc=livre&q=rancoeur&x=0&y=0&p=1&f_creator=baudelaire%2C%20charles%20%281821-1867%29) directement.</sub>

<sub>2.Par exemple, [rancune](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?ArianeWireIndex=index&p=1&lang=EN&f_typedoc=livre&q=rancune&x=0&y=0) (25244 entrées, 21e: 1619, 20e:4438, 19e:18124, 18e:398, 17e:129, 16e:60) ; [rancoeur](http://gallica.bnf.fr/Search?ArianeWireIndex=index&f_typedoc=livre&q=rancoeur&p=1&lang=EN&y=0&x=0) (3773 entrées, 21e:1843, 20e:1076, 19e:724, 18e:19, 17e:34, 16e:5 sous [*Gallica*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/html/und/propos), *la bibliothèque numérique de la Bibliothèque nationale de France et de ses partenaires (en ligne depuis 1997*).</sub>

Comment: Excellente réponse, merci notamment pour sa grande richesse de références.

Answer (score 3):

> - *La rancidité* (inconnu au petit Robert) est liée à une altération d'un corps gras, *une huile rance*.
> - *La rancœur* est lié au ressentiment ; elle reflète une désillusion liée à une situation, à une épreuve ; elle donne un goût de cendre dans la bouche, d'impuissance inacceptable, contre laquelle on ne peut plus rien.
> - *La rancune* est une rancœur personnalisée qui appelle une froide vengeance.

---

Lorsqu'on *a* de la rancune contre quelqu'un, on *est* rancunier, c'est un état qui peut être source de vengeance contre la personne visée pour se débarrasser de cette rancune.

Si on a de la rancœur, on *éprouve* de la rancœur (mais on ne peut pas *être* 'rencœurier'), c'est un sentiment obsédant sans cesse ressassé dont on ne voit pas comment s'en sortir.

Comment: Excellente réponse, merci notamment pour sa grande clarté.